# Fetch data from SQL Server table of the ERP DB

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, data-warehouse

I have pretty old ERP system running on SQL Server 2005 (about 20GB database. Largest able has 2 million rows). Unfortunately, the ERP can't run on SQL Server 2008 or newer. I have a huge amount of legacy systems as well. Some of them are VBA frontend and stored procedures as backend and business logic. Some of them are C# applications. I know it is a very bad approach and I'm looking for better solution. I fetch data directly from ERP DB with `SELECT WITH (NOLOCK)`.

If one day (hopefully soon) I will have to replace my ancient ERP with a new one, it will be a nightmare to update thousands of stored procedures, VBA and C# code.

The only solution I can think about is a definition of objects. For example, I plan to maintain P/N table which will hold all my part numbers and relevant data. On another hand, I have to merge the data from ERP to the P/N table every 5 minutes (either SSIS or stored procedure) to keep it updated. It is a huge load on my ERP DB. Considering tremendous amount of objects (warehouses, inventory data, logistics and financial transactions, engineering data) this approach will kill my ERP DB.

Can you propose a better solution?

Comment: Can you say more about why you are doing this?  Why do you need to copy the (is it Part Numbers?)  data to a new table if you can already access it directly?

Comment: Mike, I'm more than familiar with the current DB structure. I know table names (about 500 tables) and schema. If I will replace my current ERP, I will have to rebuild queries in all my applications. Instead of doing this, I'd like to create a sort of data warehouse where I will store objects. My goal is to create an abstraction level between ERP and other applications. Moreover, the abstraction level can serve other objectives such as BI, integration with CR, etc...

Comment: ok--  I understand data warehouse.  So the challenge then is that you really want to mirror or clone the ERP database.  But how to do that efficiently...  is there a difference between querying it often directly or querying it often to copy data out.  Does it sound like I understand you?

Comment: Direct querying is a bad practice and I already witness that the ERP DB performance affected badly because of persistent direct querying. In addition, lack f abstraction level will constrain me to rewrite a significant part of the code of all my applications when changing something in the ERP. Moreover, direct querying (as far as I know) is a very bad practice for BI and system integration.

Comment: Sure.  So then we're stuck with how to copy out the data frequently other than direct querying.  What database system is hosting the ERP?  My next question being, have you looked into any standard mirroring by the database system?

Comment: The ERP DB is old and rusty SQL 2005. And I can't upgrade to SQL 2008 or later since the ERP can't run on newer DB. I still haven't looked into standard mirroring because I believe that it will make the same load on the source DB, won't it?

Comment: Well, presumably they know a lot more about making it efficient than you or I do :-) .   A quick google search suggests there absolutely is mirroring starting from 2005 SP1.  I have to think you should try that before you try to reinvent it with your own query set.

Comment: I'm having fun still poking around at it... haven't had to mess with it much myself.  It looks like the magic word may be "replication" for this case...  sql server "mirroring" is really targeting server failover , and "replication" for data warehousing and other sharing scenarios.  I'll make it an Answer :-)

Comment: And I will accept it as the answer ) Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to move lots of data off the source server often, maybe you should consider the db's native solution of

- **Replication**.

You can organize it to push only what you want it to push.
It is made to operate in parallel to normal operation.  There are lots of configurations to balance getting it thorough versus not bothering the server too much (at both ends).  It can do things like read transactions logs with separate Services, avoiding running queries through the db engine at all.

There's a ton of information out there.
You can start with the official stuff at:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=sql.90).aspx
It walks you through a lot of the options, including
[choosing an overall Replication type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152565(v=sql.90).aspx),
[and considerations for Data Warehousing and Reporting scenarios.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151784(v=sql.90).aspx)

Any internet search for more help on Replication, including on SO, will turn up a lot more.